# How to get TimeZones array in swift using Chinese

Tags: swift, timezone

I need to get to the time zone array using Chinese,but ,use TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers get is English array

Answer (score 0):

`TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers` returns a list of IDs from the [IANA TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  A comprehensive list is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

These are not to be translated.  They are *identifiers*, passed as parameters to code to identify a time zone.  They are always in English, and their exact spelling, casing, and punctuation should remain intact.  If you were to translate it, you would find they are not usable in any API.

If your goal is to display a human-readable translated string in a UI, then you should use the localized names provided by the [Unicode CLDR project](http://cldr.unicode.org/).  I am not an iOS developer, so I can't be certain, but from reading the docs, I believe these are already available to you by using the [`localizedName`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timezone/2292835-localizedname) instance method of the `TimeZone` class.